# Error occurs during installation of Robot Framework with Python on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, python-3.x, path, robotframework

I have installed "python-3.3.0.msi" successfully and set up PATH as "C:\Python33;" on Windows 7. After that I tried to install Robot Framework by using "robotframework-2.7.7.win32.exe" (double click on the .exe file). At the last step of installation I found the following error:

```
File "<string>", line 35
    except Exception, err:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I clicked on "Finish" button --> Installation wizard was disappeared. I set the PATH as "C:\Python33\Scripts". Then I checked the version by using the command "pybot --version" at command prompt. Below error was shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 140, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 102, in _get_module_details
    loader = get_loader(mod_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\pkgutil.py", line 482, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\pkgutil.py", line 499, in find_loader
    pkg = importlib.import_module(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1577, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1023, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 869, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\robot\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from robot.rebot import rebot, rebot_cli
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\robot\rebot.py", line 268, in <module>
    from robot.conf import RebotSettings
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\robot\conf\__init__.py", line 17, in <mo
    from .settings import RobotSettings, RebotSettings
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\robot\conf\settings.py", line 172
    except EnvironmentError, err:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I solve the above error?

Comment: Looks like Robot Framework doesn't support Python 3 yet. You should try to use Python 2.7 instead. (Python 3 changes lots of things in the language syntax, including the syntax for catching exceptions shown in this traceback.)

Comment: @Schnouki: Thanks a lot. Yes, It has been solved by using Python2.7.3 instead of Python3.3.0

Comment: python3.3.0 is still incompatible with robotframework2.7.7

Comment: @Schnouki You should've written that as an answer, so the asker can accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Robot Framework doesn't support Python 3 yet. You should try to use Python 2.7 instead. (Python 3 changes lots of things in the language syntax, including the syntax for catching exceptions shown in this traceback). So, follow the following installation steps:

1. Install Python2.7.3
2. Install robotframework2.7.7
3. set PATH as "C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\"
4. Verify the installation by using the command "pybot --version" at command prompt. If everything is OK, the
   following message will be displayed:
   "Robot Framework 2.7.7 (Python 2.7.3 on win32)"

Answer (score 2):

you should run "pip install robotframework-python3"
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-python3